.comments is not a valid Plugin property after upgrading from 0.72.15 to 0.76.0
Recently I have been upgrading my react native version from 0.72.15 to 0.75.0 following this Upgrade helper
I faced several conflict and then fixed, finally I got stuck with .comments is not a valid Plugin property in my index.js file
This is what I have in index.js
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

Initially I am trying to fix IOS app. Any suggestions about this issue?
Update - 1


Do you have some sort of stack trace for that error?

@ewokx I have updated my questions with a screenshot, I couldn't find much details there.

I have just figured it out, I have used a commented line in babel.config.js that was the issue
